# How to use custom task activity inside while in visual studio 2010 sequential workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

How to use custom task activity inside while in visual studio 2010 sequential workflow?

I am using custom task activity which is in replicator activity and this is executed inside while condition .

but unfortunately i am not able to get the  properties which has been set in workflow .

Note:- If While Condition is removed then it is working fine...

is anyone can provide solution why the values are not set when it is while activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider having global properties and assign them in the workflow constructor. That way they should be available in the while loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the help using Dynamic object of replicator it is now working
 Just have to changed the below code

private void replicatorActivity1_ChildInitialized(object sender, ReplicatorChildEventArgs e)
        {

```
 SPTaskActivity customactivity = (SPTaskActivity)e.Activity;

    customactivity = TaskTitle;
            customactivity = TaskAssignedTo;
}
```

and it worked.

Regards,

Salman